# When to create or reuse an Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elastic-cloud

My team has been using a minimal Elasticsearch implementation for a year now, and we'd now like to additionally use ES for a new and totally different use case, using different and essentially unrelated data. While I have been reading about Clusters, Nodes, and ES in general, I do not intuitively understand whether or not we should create a new cluster for this, or add the data into our existing cluster. Where is a good place to look to better understand the factors involved in this decision? We're using ES hosted by Elastic Cloud, v5.2.x for the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the resources available, it does not hurt to use the same cluster for multiple types of data/use cases.

If I were you I would just take a look at the Monitoring page to check out your usage statistics like storage, search rates, indexing rates, etc. to see if you have the resources available. If so, you don't really need to have separate clusters.